# Where can I find neo4j jdbc driver?

Tags: jdbc, neo4j

The official neo4j page has a mention to a jdbc driver test ([here](http://neo4j.com/blog/wanted-your-help-in-testing-neo4j-jdbc-driver/)). But the jdbc link appear to be broken.

Someone knows where can I find a jdbc driver (jar file) to neo4j?

Answer (score 5):

2. 1.4 is the latest in the maven repository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-jdbc

Download from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-jdbc or use as a maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency
```

FYI this version works fine with Neo4j 2.1.5 (I'm using it), but have not tried it against 2.1.6

**Update for Neo4j 2.3**

Snapshot available:

```
     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc</artifactId>
          <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
     </dependency>

     <repository>
          <id>neo4j-public</id>
          <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/groups/public</url>
          <releases>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
              <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
     </repository>
```

Comment: Putting the dependency in the pom.xml results in `Missing artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-jdbc:jar:2.1.4`. Any idea why?

Comment: @findusl I have this problem too. Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: @dwjohnston Yes, by now it works. I don't remeber exactly what i did but i think i added this: 
`<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>neo4j-public</id>
      <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/groups/public</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>`

Comment: @findusl Yeah, I solved it by using a different artifact.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this dependency to solve this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with</version>
        <classifier>dependencies</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

Note that it does appear to be an older version of neo4j though.

Answer (score 0):

2.1.4 version does work but also add the repository in the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>neo4j-public</id>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/groups/public</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the direct Neo4j JDBC driver page to download

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/releases