# How do I set up a jdbc connection to neo4j?

Tags: jdbc, neo4j, jdbctemplate

My understanding is that while jdbc is typically used for SQL queries, because an SQL query is essentially just a string, JDBC isn't going to know whether it's an SQL query or a cypher query.

From what I can see I just need to import the neo4j jdbc driver, and use that to pass my cypher query to the neo4j database.

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Now I'm trying something like this:

```
    this.dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(this.DBURL,this.USERNAME, this.PASSWORD);


    this.dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");        
    this.jdbcTemplate  = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource); 

    String qq = "MATCH (n:Individual) RETURN n LIMIT 25;";      
    Map<String,Object> res = jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(qq); //I actually just want to return a JSON string, but this is the only example I can find for now
```

This code will give me:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:127)
```

What am I doing wrong here? What is the correct name of the driver class?

I've also tried

```
Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");
```

and I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
```

Comment: Ok, it looks like the problem is that my neo4j driver isn't being imported by maven properly. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808257/where-can-i-find-neo4j-jdbc-driver

Answer (score -1):

You usually have to do `Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver")` first to load the driver class.

What does your JDBC URL look like?

Please note that the JDBC driver (in the remote case) will return a `Map` with the data of each node.

Comment: I've tried that, and I still get an error. Check updated post. Can you explain what Class.forName does?

Comment: jdbc:neo4j://myhost:8080/url

Comment: Not 'usually' since 2007.

Answer (score -1):

try to change
**`Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver")`**

on

**`Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()`**

Comment: The question shows a "ClassNotFoundException" thrown. Trying to create an instance of a class that could not even be loaded is not going to help.